# How to allocate memory for a structure with a pointer to an array of structures in C?

Tags: c, arrays, struct, nested, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a function which create and return a new object for a list, but I'm having troubles with allocation of memory (Error: core dumped). I figured it's because of '*model', which is a pointer to an array for structures. I'm quite new to dynamic memory allocation and not sure what and how to allocate the right amount of memory.

Function:

```
// Return a newly created object based on the arguments provided. 
object_t *create_object(SDL_Surface *surface, triangle_t *model, int numtriangles)
{
    // Allocate memory for a new object
    object_t *new_obj = malloc(sizeof(object_t));
        if (new_obj == NULL)
            return NULL;
    // Allocate memory for the model array
    triangle_t *arrayPtr = malloc((sizeof(triangle_t))*numtriangles);
        if (arrayPtr == NULL)
            return NULL;

    // Assign values
    arrayPtr = model;
    new_obj->model = arrayPtr;
    new_obj->numtriangles = numtriangles;
    new_obj->surface = surface;
    // Return created object
    return new_obj;
}
```

Function call in main:

```
object_t *ball = create_object(surface, sphere_model, SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES);
```

Structures:

```
typedef struct object object_t;
struct object {
    float       scale;
    float       rotation;
    float       tx, ty;
    float       speedx, speedy;
    unsigned int ttl;          
    int         numtriangles;
    triangle_t  *model;
    SDL_Surface *surface;
};

typedef struct triangle triangle_t;
struct triangle {
    int x1, y1;
    int x2, y2;
    int x3, y3;
    unsigned int fillcolor;
    float scale;
    int tx, ty;
    float rotation;
    SDL_Rect rect;
    int sx1, sy1;
    int sx2, sy2;
    int sx3, sy3;
};
```

Array:

```
#define SPHERE_NUMTRIANGLES    478   // <-- Array size
triangle_t sphere_model[] = {
{
.x1=-1,
.y1=-500,
.x2=-1,
.y2=-489,
.x3=-1,
.y3=-500,
.fillcolor=0xeeeeee,
.scale=1.0
},
{
.x1=-1,
.y1=-489,
.x2=-1,
.y2=-500,
.x3=40,
.y3=-489,
.fillcolor=0xbb0000,
.scale=1.0
},
...
```

I tried `object_t *new_obj = malloc(sizeof(object_t) + (sizeof(triangle_t)*numtriangles));` but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

```
// Assign values
arrayPtr = model;
```

What you do here is discard newly allocated pointer contained in arrayPtr, and just assign it to point to the same memory as `model`. It might crash if `model` has shorter lifetime (e.g. allocated on stack) and is no longer valid pointer after function returns.

I believe your intention here was to `copy` content from model array into your new array, so you should have done something like:

```
memcpy(arrayPtr, model, (sizeof(triangle_t))*numtriangles);
```

Answer (score 2):

So, looks like `object_t *new_obj = malloc(sizeof(object_t) + (sizeof(triangle_t)*numtriangles));` is an unnecessarily large allocation.

I say this because this line in the create_object method `arrayPtr = model;` is assigning the memory address of the passed-in triangle_t* 'model', to the newly allocated arrayPtr.

However, on the line above this you allocated a load of memory to the arrayPtr address... This would therefore lead to a memory leak as you are allocating the memory to that address, and then changing the address of the pointer (so it no longer points at *that* memory) but you aren't calling free on that memory, so it will sit on the heap for the duration of your program.

With the line `arrayPtr = model;` I suspect what you actually want to do is perform a memory copy of the **contents** of the model address, to the newly allocated arrayPtr address.
This should therefore actually look like:

`memcpy(arrayPtr, model, sizeof(triangle_t) * numTriangles);`

Sadly I am unable to run your code as I am at work without access to a C compiler however, I would suspect that your error is caused by you free'ing the memory of the 'model' pointer that is still being accessed by the object_t struct due to the accidental misuse of the '=' assignment operator.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help. 
My thought process was to assign a pointer enough memory for the array, then make a copy of set array by assigning it to the pointer.

Anyway, this did did the trick:

```
new_obj->model = malloc(sizeof(triangle_t)*numtriangles);
    if (new_obj == NULL)
        return NULL;
bcopy(model, new_obj->model, sizeof(triangle_t)*numtriangles);
```